# Rails: Adding years to Feb 29

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

Try this with latest Rails (6.0.2.1):

```rb
Date.new(2020,2,29) + 1.year + 1.year + 1.year + 1.year
=> Wed, 28 Feb 2024

Date.new(2020,2,29) + 4.years
=> Thu, 29 Feb 2024
```

or this one:

```rb
Date.new(2020,2,28) + 1.year
=> Sun, 28 Feb 2021

Date.new(2020,2,29) + 1.year
=> Sun, 28 Feb 2021
```

Bug or feature?

Answer (score 1):

From my understanding it is not a bug at all. 
In first case `ruby` adds *each* year to previous. As we know `Date.new(2021,2,29)` is invalid date, the valid date is `Date.new(2021,2,28)` so result is totally expected. Adding 4 years as one operation seems fair and logic also, result is `Thu, 29 Feb 2024`, but if you add only 3 years the result will be `Tue, 28 Feb 2023`.

Comment: Right, but it's a bit strange that `x + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 != x + 4`.